# How to write this MongoDb update operator

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an 'applications' collection in the following form:

```
{ 
  "_id" : "<id>", 
  "versions" : {
      "2_2_1" : 5, 
      "2_2_2" : 38, 
      "2_2_3" : 76
  }
}
```

I want to increment the version number based on the version of application that sends a request. How can I write the $inc operator for my update query?

I can't seem to get my query working because the incremented version number can always vary from request to request. I can't get the positional $ operator working correctly for my query.

Comment: what send by your request is key name or value like is `2_2_1` or `5` ?

Comment: The request sends the version number, i.e. "2_2_1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) in order to access the specifc value under "version", but also you are going to have to "build" the object key by whatever language you are using.

As a JavaScript example:

```js
var request = "2_2_1";
var update = { "$inc": { } };

update["$inc"]["versions." + request] = 1;
```

This yields:

```js
{ "$inc": { "versions.2_2_1": 1 } }
```

So you just perform the update:

```js
db.collection.update({ "_id": id },update);
```

If that "request" version sub-key exists then it is "incremented" from it's previous value. If it is a "new" key then the initial value will be `1`.

Comment: This works! Thanks, I never thought of building my update query like that, I was trying to do it via the $ positional operator and couldn't get it right.