# Mongodb upsert field in document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document in the following form:

```
{ 
    "_id" : <id of document>, 
    "inventory" : [
        {
            "entity_id" : "<id>", 
            "ad_type" : "ADTYPE"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm not sure if this is possible in mongo but I am trying to construct an upsert query on the above document where I will insert an empty array if inventory doesn't exist or push to the array if inventory has one or more elements.

I tried using the findAndModify function but I don't think that will work.

Comment: Hint: The answer to this does not differ that much from your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31200351/5031275)

Comment: did u tried `update({"_id" : ObjectId("55967245eb075a749963c74d")},{$addToSet:{"inventory":{"entity_id" : 1,"ad_type" : "ADTYPE4"}}},true,false)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({"_id":"value"}).forEach(
  function(doc){
    if(doc.hasOwnProperty('inventory'))
     {
       db.collection.update({"_id":doc._id},
       {"$push":{"inventory": "new value"}});
     }
   else
    {
       db.collection.update({"_id":doc._id},
       {"$set":{"inventory": new Array() }});
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

"collection" is array, "subcollection" is object.
The script adds new field "rank" to array element with index 1.
If the field doesn't exist the script creates "rank" and set value, If the field exists the script update value.

```html
db.userCollection.update(
   { "_id": ObjectId("5a1e7aefd1928362e53c5c48"), 
     $and: [ { "collection.1.subcollection.id": "1234" }, 
        { "collection.1.rank": {"$ne": -1 }} 
       ] 
   },
   { $set: { "collection.1.rank": "5" } 
   }
)
```